# Having problem to make something responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I'm trying to put an oval in the middle of the screen and surround it with an oval marquee text.

For some reason, the oval marquee text is not following the SVG path and becomes a normal circle! I want to make it bigger a little bit bigger than the image, while it remains as an oval and be responsive.

Like: Oval = image * 1.2

I have attached the code:

```js
function Init() {
  let w = wrap.clientWidth;
  let h = wrap.clientHeight;
  ellipse.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${w}  ${h}`);
  let d = `M${w / 10},${h / 2}A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 *
    w /
    10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 *
    h /
    10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 * w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 *
    w /
    10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 * h / 10}`;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  let path_length = thePath.getTotalLength();


  //begin at a bigger size than needed
  let font_size = 100;
  ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size + "px";

  // while the text length is bigger than half path length 
  while (tp.getComputedTextLength() > path_length / 2) {
    //reduce the font size
    font_size -= .50;
    //reset the font size 
    ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size + "px";
  }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  window.addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 0);

let so = 0;

function Marquee() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee);
  tp.setAttributeNS(null, "startOffset", so + "%");
  if (so >= 50) {
    so = 0;
  }
  so += 0.3;
}

Marquee();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

.pes
{
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 59;
}

text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}

.rotating-img-10 {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 49;
}

.rotating-img-10: after {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pes" id="wrap">
      <svg id="ellipse" class="sv" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <path id="thePath" class="sve" fill="transparent" d="M100,500A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500 A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500" />
        <text fill="#000">
          <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" dy="5" id="tp" lengthAdjust="spacing" class="svd">● i'm a beatuiful placeholder for what you need and i'm rotating for no reason! can someone help me?</textPath>
        </text>
      </svg>
</div>


<img class="rotating-img-10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emdesigner-or/MOONLIGHT-2021/main/ezgif.com-gif-maker.webp" alt="rotated-image">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `svg` is square, you need to stretch it a bit. `transform:scale(1,1.x)` can help

Possible example:

```js
function Init() {
  let w = wrap.clientWidth;
  let h = wrap.clientHeight;
  ellipse.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${w}  ${h}`);
  let d = `M${w / 10},${h / 2}A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 *
    w /
    10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 *
    h /
    10} A${4 * w / 10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${9 * w / 10} ${5 * h / 10} A${4 *
    w /
    10},${4 * h / 10} 0 0 0 ${w / 10} ${5 * h / 10}`;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  let path_length = thePath.getTotalLength();


  //begin at a bigger size than needed
  let font_size = 100;
  ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size + "px";

  // while the text length is bigger than half path length 
  while (tp.getComputedTextLength() > path_length / 2) {
    //reduce the font size
    font_size -= .50;
    //reset the font size 
    ellipse.style.fontSize = font_size + "px";
  }
}



window.setTimeout(function() {
  Init();
  window.addEventListener("resize", Init, false);
}, 0);

let so = 0;

function Marquee() {
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee);
  tp.setAttributeNS(null, "startOffset", so + "%");
  if (so >= 50) {
    so = 0;
  }
  so += 0.1;
}

Marquee();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

.pes
{
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 59;
}

text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
}

.rotating-img-10 {
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 49;
}

.rotating-img-10: after {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}
svg {transform:scale(1.1,1.24)}
```

```html
<div class="pes" id="wrap">
      <svg id="ellipse" class="sv" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <path id="thePath" class="sve" fill="transparent" d="M100,500A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500 A400,400 0 0 0 900 500 A400,400 0 0 0 100 500" />
        <text fill="#000">
          <textPath xlink:href="#thePath" dy="5" id="tp" lengthAdjust="spacing" class="svd">● i'm a beatuiful placeholder for what you need and i'm rotating for no reason! can someone help me?</textPath>
        </text>
      </svg>
</div>


<img class="rotating-img-10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emdesigner-or/MOONLIGHT-2021/main/ezgif.com-gif-maker.webp" alt="rotated-image">
```

to spin it more inside or outside, increase both scale value keeping that average ratio of  1:1.1 .